# ¿Son "palabra" y "término" sinónimos en alguno de sus significados?

Tags: sinónimos

Siempre pensé que "palabra" en un lenguaje se refería a un carácter o conjunto de caracteres que tienen un significado, y que por otra parte, "término" era un conjunto de palabras que tienen un significado (por ejemplo: *fútbol americano*).

De ser estas definiciones correctas, una palabra sería sólo una "palabra", pero no un "término". ¿Es esto así? ¿O "palabra" y "término" pueden ser sinónimos en alguno de sus significados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partes de unas definiciones que no parecen del todo correctas. El DLE define
[**palabra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RUl938s) como:

> 1. f. **Unidad lingüística**, dotada generalmente de significado, que se separa de las demás mediante pausas potenciales en la pronunciación y blancos en la escritura.

y [**término**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZZ0hKcs) como

> 8. m. **palabra** (‖ **unidad lingüística**).

Por lo que, en esas acepciones, sí son sinónimos.

Comment: Bueno, en Google me salen 20 definiciones de la palabra término.. y en otros lugares hay algunas más que no están ahí

Comment: @Pablo: por supuesto que hay más acepcione, pero la 1ª de palabra y la 8ª de término son sinónimos

Answer (score 3):

> De ser estas definiciones correctas, una palabra sería sólo una "palabra", pero no un "término". ¿Es esto así?

Contestanto esta parte de la pregunta, según [este texto](http://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0718-09342008000200002), perteneciente a un discurso de incorporación a la Academia Chilena de la Lengua, se podría concluir que tienes razón en tu argumentación. Aunque todo el texto habla de las diferencias y simulitudes entre "término" y "palabra", esta parte hace claridad repecto a la diferencia:

> El término, en este contexto, es el nombre o designación de un concepto en un campo temático particular. Puede tratarse de una palabra del lenguaje general que adopta un sentido especializado, una palabra creada con un sentido especializado, un sintagma o grupo de palabras con un sentido único y especializado, un símbolo, una fórmula química o matemática, un nombre científico en latín o en griego, un acrónimo, una sigla, la denominación o título oficial de un cargo, organismo o entidad administrativa.

Y se agregan más explicaciones respecto a lo que distingue a un término de una palabra:

> - su relación unívoca (fenómeno denominado monosemia) con el concepto especializado que designa en un campo del saber específico;
> - la estabilidad de la relación entre la forma léxica con que se designa a un concepto y el contenido semántico que ella porta (fenómeno denominado lexicalización);
> - la frecuencia de su uso y su entorno contextual (co-ocurrencia) relativamente fijo (lo que se conoce como fraseología);
> - los indicadores tipográficos (cursiva, negrita, comillas, etc.) con que se marcan en un texto;
> - la existencia de un conjunto más bien limitado de estructuras morfológicas y léxicas: por lo general suelen ser sustantivos (simples, derivados o compuestos), como, por ejemplo, “telecomunicaciones”, aunque en ocasiones los términos también pueden ser verbos, “telecopiar”, adjetivos o sintagmas nominales, “Organización Internacional del Trabajo”, verbales o adjetivales.